# How can I close CharmBar programmatically in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, charms-bar

I need to closing charmBar programmatically, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try focusing on another control. For example, call

```
this.Focus();
```

Comment: Thank you @keyboardP But I am not in *.xaml.cs :(

Comment: Are you using MVVM? (Or another language?)

Comment: Yes, I am using it and sorry for late answer.

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay - No problem, this might help. It'll manage focus via the Visual State http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2011/10/using-visual-states-to-set-focus-on.html

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay - Just to add, you might want to try `this.Focus` in the code behind to see if it actually works and then use the attached property in the link to conform to the MVVM guidelines.