# How to programmatically close the print UI on a Windows 10 application?

Tags: c#, printing, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am designing a Windows 10 Universal application using this https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing/cs repository as a guide. I currently have fully functional printing by calling:

```
await Printmanager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
```

In my application there is also an activity timer that logs the user out after a certain amount of time inactive. This part is working fine, but I am unable to close the print ui upon logout.

Note: Normally to close a windows async operations, you can do something similar to:

```
IAsyncOperation<bool> printOperation = Printmanager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
printOperation.Cancel();
```

This works for other AsyncOperation occurences, but I cannot get it to work for the print UI, as the print UI is not a child process of the app, but is a seperate process itself

Thanks in advance!

Also, it seems there was a solution to kill processes in Windows 8 which is no longer supported in Windows 10 applications (Process.GetProcessByName .... or FindWindow)

Perhaps there is someway to kill a Windows 10 process by name?

Comment: you could use FindWindow (winAPI) or Process.GetProcessesByName(<name>) then kill the process.

Comment: hmm, I'm unable to get either of those to be recognized by Visual Studio 2015 (with the header:
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.ComponentModel; )

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessByName(String), https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx  and FindWindow is a C++ method so you will need to use DLLImport and supply the signature.   Search SO for C# FindWindow

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't that only work for Windows Desktop Apps?

Comment: FindWindow will find any top level window on the desktop, correct.  GetProcessByName should work with anything listed in the task manager.

Comment: In the GetProcessByName documentation it says: Windows 2000 Professional [desktop apps only], additionally the Systems.Diagnotics dll doesn't appear to be supported by Windows 10. Again, I could be wrong (and hope I am!).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85315/discussion-between-gwcoderguy-and-sorceri).

Comment: my bad, the link was to findwindow, here is the GetProcessByName link, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you sure you can use this in a Windows 10 Universal app, I'm unable to get the dll

Comment: FindWindow cannot be used in Windows Store Apps, this function is part of the GDI API, it is based on Windows handles which do not even exist for Windows Store/Universal/Phone/Metro/WinRT Apps.By the way the class System.Diagnostics.Process is also restricted.

Comment: @gwcoderguy The print UI is a WinRT Charm, so this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469978/how-can-i-close-charmbar-programmaticly-in-winrt

Comment: Are you sure this is still supported in Windows 10? When I try this.Focus(); visual studio suggests generating a focus method.

Comment: I think [it is supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702161.aspx). Are you sure you are calling it from the right place?

Comment: ah, you are correct. However, even upon a successful call (I check the return value) it neither diverts focus from the print UI nor closes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

**All the Metro-style applications work in the highly sandboxed environment and there is no way to directly start an external application.**
Taken  from this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/14e2be68-ef86-4480-a3fd-6ddf7ec7d1f1/how-to-start-a-external-program-from-metro-app?forum=winappswithcsharp)

maybe the solution is creating a proxy.
[How to Start a external Program from Metro App](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/14e2be68-ef86-4480-a3fd-6ddf7ec7d1f1/how-to-start-a-external-program-from-metro-app?forum=winappswithcsharp)

This could help you, because you can kill the process indirectly.

I hope this helps.